# O_WRONLY undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
char data [ 6 ];
main ( ) {
int len;
desc = open ( "Resultat", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0666 );
if ( desc != -1 ) {
len = write ( desc, &data, sizeof ( data ) );
if ( len != sizeof ( data ) )
printf ( "ERROR" );
} }
```

this is my code and i'm getting the error

```
O_WRONLY undeclared (first use in this function)
O_CREAT undeclared (first use in this function)
O_EXCL undeclared (first use in this function)
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: What platform are you on?  This builds for me on CentOS 5 and CentOS 6, once I assign an `int` datatype to `desc`

Comment: #include <sys/stat.h> ?

Comment: ubuntu 9.10, i added #include<sys/stat.h> but still same error..

Comment: grep O_WRONLY /usr/include/*.h

Comment: My machine (mac) shows `O_WRONLY` defined in `sys/fcntl.h`, try including that.

Comment: it worked thank u.. i compiled my prog (gcc test.c -o test) it create a new file named test but i can't access it.. sorry i'm new to linux what should i do to get what my program said

Comment: The problem with a program called `test` is that the shell has a built-in function called `test` (aka `[`) too.  That gets called in preference to your program unless you run `./test` (even if `.` is on `$PATH`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Which is a good reason *not* to have `.` in your `$PATH`. and to get into the habit of typing `./foo` to execute `foo` in the current directory. Given those habits, calling a program `test` is not a problem.

Comment: `main()` should be `int main(void)`. `len` should be of type `ssize_t` (the type returned by `write`), not `int`. There's no reason to define `data` outside the `main` function.

Comment: Did you really get that error for that exact code? Did you copy-and-paste both the source code and the error message into the question? I ask because when I compile your code on Linux Mint (an Ubuntu derivative), the compiler doesn't complain about `O_WRONLY` -- but it does tell me that `desc` is undeclared.

Answer (score 25):

@Kevin is right. On my Arch installation, according to [`man fcntl.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/fcntl.h.html), you need to `#include <fcntl.h>` to get access to `O_WRONLY`.

To use `open()`, you also need to `#include <sys/stat.h>`.

Answer (score 6):

I have tried this code in my machine (Ubuntu 12.0.4). But I didn't get any error messages like you got.

According to the man page of `open()` you are probably missing [`#include <sys/stat.h>`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html).

Comment: Indeed. You should always read the man page for any function you're calling, and make sure you've `#include`d any headers it specifies. For `open`, the required headers are `<sys/types.h>`, `<sys/stat.h>`, and `<fcntl.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

Manual pages for [`open(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

Please verify that you have each and every one of the required includes.